# How does gnome system monitor calculates the amount of used memory?

Tags: linux, gnome, monitoring

How does gnome system monitor calculates the amount of used memory? I tend to trust the values displayed by the system monitor because are consistent and do agree with the amount of ram used when running a test an application. However when I compare those values with the numbers displayed in /proc/meminfo I see no connection at all. Currently on my laptop I have 3.5 GB of ram and the amount of used memory is shown to be 814 MB. On the other hand here is what /proc/meminfo shows:

```
MemTotal:        3715348 kB
MemFree:          923216 kB
Buffers:          154144 kB
Cached:          1804380 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1190432 kB
Inactive:        1331876 kB
Active(anon):     609064 kB
Inactive(anon):    83176 kB
Active(file):     581368 kB
Inactive(file):  1248700 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       2104476 kB
SwapFree:        2104476 kB
Dirty:               132 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        563820 kB
Mapped:           137208 kB
Shmem:            128456 kB
Slab:             108932 kB
SReclaimable:      77224 kB
SUnreclaim:        31708 kB
KernelStack:        3000 kB
PageTables:        27924 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3962148 kB
Committed_AS:    1870184 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      379280 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359259364 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8688 kB
DirectMap2M:     3840000 kB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare what System Monitor shows to `$ free -m`

The amount shown as "in use" by System Monitor is the amount in the second line of output from `free`. AFAIK, this is the amount of RAM actually used, excluding what is cached. `free -m` often shows much more as "used" (first line of output) because it includes that used by the cache. This is not necessarily a bad thing, as empty/unused RAM is wasted RAM; rather have it "in use" as cache than sitting empty.